Expo builds a very large apk
I recently learnt react native and build a simple hello world program with expo cli, howerver after running the build to generate the app the apk was 100mbs , how can i unistall things that are not needed to make the app smaller
I created a bare minimum react project and still the output was 70mb

Platform portability comes at a price. You app need to include a complete JavaScript runtime, all libraries and code for all possible API calls you may call in react native. Plus the standard compatibility libraries for Java/Kotlin code. If you want really small APK files develop in Java without any compatibility libraries. Then you can get 20Kb for a Hello World apk file.
